# Loop through taxonomies and loop through their terms (Newbie question)

Tags: posts, customization, terms

I have a custom post type called 'classe'. I am trying to loop through each of these posts to get a list of their taxonomies and their terms. Here is my code :

```
$type = 'classe';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> true
    );

    $loop = null;
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $loop->have_posts() ):
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            $taxonomies = ???? //Get taxonomies

            $result = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
                $result .= '<div class="grid-content">';
                $result .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() .'</h2>';
                $result .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() .'</p>';
                foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
                    $terms = ???? //Get terms
                    $result .= '<h4>' . $taxonomy . '</h4>';
                    foreach($terms as $term){
                        $result .= '<p>' . $term . '</p>';
                    }
                }
                $result .= '</div>';
            $result .= '</div>';
            echo $result;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to retrieve the terms of the post you're looping through.

```
$taxonomies = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy-name');
```